# How to use libc function in simulating asm code in c?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, compilation

Test platform is Linux 32 bit.

So basically I am trying to simulate/translate the assembly code using c,

currently my code can deal small assembly code with system call(int 80)
and others..

But when I am thinking to translate the libc function calling parts, 
I am quite confused..

Here is an example:

```
section .data
.LC0:
message db "this is a test %d %d %f ", 10

section .text 

   movl    $1, 32(%esp)
   movl    $1, 36(%esp)
   movl    $1, 40(%esp)
   movl    $1, 44(%esp)
   movl    44(%esp), %eax
   movl    %eax, 16(%esp)
   movl    40(%esp), %eax
   movl    %eax, 12(%esp)
   movl    36(%esp), %eax
   movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
   movl    32(%esp), %eax
   movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
   movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
   call    printf
```

And I am confused on how to translate into some thing like this:

```
   unsigned int v_ebp[100000];
   unsigned int v_esp = v_ebp + 9999;

   ........

   printf(.LC0, (unsigned int)(v_esp - 4), (unsigned int)(v_esp - 8), (unsigned int)(v_esp - 12));
```

I am thinking a relatively "stupid" way is to simlulate the way printf analysis 
the first argument, find out how much variables it is asked to use (which should equal the number of %xx in general), and obtain them 
one by one on the simulated stack

It seems this way is doable, but if I choose this way, 
I have to do the similiar thing for
nearly all the libc functions in the assembly codes... 
which is so tedious...

So my question is am I on the right way..? 
Is there any better solution on this issue?

Could any one give me some help ..? Thank you!

Comment: Why a libc function would have to be treated differently from any other function?

Comment: @n.m. Sorry I made a mistake... I can only deal with function call without arguments...

Comment: Why do you need to know what the arguments are? The assembly language doesn't care about arguments. It only knows about a bunch of registers and a bunch of memory cells.  "Arguments" is what *you* call some of the registers and cells. The CPU doesn't care. Just implement whatever the programmer's manual says about each instruction.

Comment: Good luck with an optimizing compiler, which might optimize away a lot of operations to keep the stack "sane" in the context of nested function calls, or calls that closely follow each other. I doubt very much it's possible to guess the number of arguments to each function in such environments.

Comment: @n.m. function call can be implemented as this way, but how about the libc function call?

Comment: @n.m. He probably wants his emulator, when it encounters a "call something" instruction, to pull the parameters from the stack, call the "real" libc function, then return to the emulator.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Yes, for the function call, I can just simulate exactly as the assembly code do, but for libc function, I don't know how... actually my assembly code are all disassembled from elf code, and thus I have to deal with the libc call problem...

Comment: You do have the libc binaries lying around, do you? Just interpret their assembly instructions. Or perhaps you want to execute these functions directly, not via emulation?

Comment: I mean, you can disassemble libc code from elf just the same exact way you disassemble user code from elf.

Comment: @n.m. Is it possible to execute libc functions directly..?

Comment: Most programs execute libc and all other functions directly, as opposed to emulating them instruction by instruction. So I would say it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you are simulating has enough debug information in the binary that you know the function calls are libc calls, then you can simulate those calls using the calling convention for that processor as keshlam is saying.  You might have to parse the formatting to determine how many parameters to expect and then for each parameter you have to simulate that parameter take the ram or registers you are simulating translate those to variables in your simulator then make the libc call.

It may be easier to not care, dont bother with libc calls at all, only system calls, int 80 and such.  printf and any other of these calls is just more machine code that you just simulate, then eventually it will make a lower level system call, put a string or output one character or write to file or whatever, and you simulate that.

```
a=7;
printf("Hello %d\n");
```

as far as you are concerned is a bunch of machine instructions operating on ram and registers, alu ops, loads, stores, etc.  Then eventually you will either get a system call to output "Hello 7\n") or you will get a series of system calls output H output e output l output l output o output ' ' output 7 output CR, output LF.  And you just handle that system call...

Comment: Hi dwelch, thank again for your great help! Well, basically the assembly code is disassembly from binary (like bzip, gzip and others..) so it seems that I **have to** deal with libc call... :( I guess I have to deal with them one by one... again, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To call the library functions directly, you'll have to know what their arguments are and what the calling conventions are, so you can extract the former from the latter on your emulated stack, call the function, and then adjust your emulated stack to reflect the result of that call.